# I want to create a page where I have a button and the button click open other buttons

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am beginning with a Project, where the use case is that I have a button or image (say element-1) at the center of the page. Once i click on this, I get some connected buttons/images (say element-2,element-3,element-4) shown up around that button/image (element-1). After I click on one of the new button/image(element-2), it opens new button/image(element-5,element-6) connected to element-2.

So, it is more like a navigation where user goes from one element to another but the route of navigation is shown along.

I am not sure if i have been able to explain my requirement.

Can someone point me to some example of similar kind?

I am thinking that jquery/bootstrap should work. Please help in pointing me to an example

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you could place the buttons on the page and set display:none. then when you click the button you could use $("#div").show() or hide() to show and hide the buttons

Comment: What you describe is a tree structure, the presentation of which can be achieved with many [jQuery tree plugins](https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=opera&q=jquery+tree+plugin). You will need to investigate to find one that gives the style of presentation you want.

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
<script>
    function toggleButtons() {
        $("#btn1").hide();
        $("#btn2").show();
        $("#btn4").show();
    }
</script>

<div id="btn1" onclick="toggleButtons()" ></div>
```